# Como gerar Thumbnail de um Video para Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, view, thumbnail

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para android, uma das telas do mesmo deve gerar thumbnails de videos e exibir as mesmas em uma lista. Como a imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui gerar thumbnails de imagens, porém já tentei diversas maneiras para gerar as thumbnails dos videos, e nada é exibido na tela quando testo o aplicativo.
Minha ultima tentativa foi criar apenas uma thumbnail de um video, porém como nas outras tentativas nada é exibido.

Atualmente o código está como segue abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="patricia.videothumbnail.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Titulo do Video"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textColor="@color/icons"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView thumbnail_mini = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);


        //caminho para o video, testei de diversas formas
        //1ª tentativa              
        String filePath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.destruction;

        //2º tentativa
        //String filePath = "/storage/external_SD/destruction.mp4";

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;

        // MINI_KIND: 512 x 384 thumbnail
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        thumbnail_mini.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
    }
}
```

Segundo a documentação do Android e diversos exemplos que encontrei, este código deveria funcionar.
Alguém tem uma ideia do que pode estar faltando, ou alguma outra solução?

ps: por uma sugestão já tentei utilizar a biblioteca Glide, continuo com o mesmo problema.

ps2: A tela fica desta forma quando testo o app
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está acontecendo algum erro no console ou o `Bitmap` simplesmente não aparece? A minha sugestão seria utilizar o [`Glide`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) por duas razões: ele consegue recuperar um thumbnail para vídeos e ele faz isso de forma assíncrona, que é a melhor forma caso esteja planejando realizar isso em um Adapter.

Comment: Nenhum erro é mostrado no console, o bitmap apenas não é exibido na tela.

Comment: Tentei usar a biblioteca com vídeo e nada é exibido, com imagens funcionou. :/
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Este foi o resultado.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhu1d8l7ymqri0i/Captura%20de%20tela%202016-02-19%2019.42.05.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Bom, primeiramente, nunca passe o caminho do arquivo dessa forma. Faça assim:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"destruction.mp4");
```

Daí, pra de fato pegar o caminho, use `file.getAbsolutePath()`

Isso lhe dará o caminho correto da forma correta.

Agora, verifique se realmente o caminho que você está passando é esse mesmo. Nunca acessei arquivos pelo Genymotion, verifique o caminho do arquivo.

Como você não mencionou, vou perguntar. Você verificou as permissões no Manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a biblioteca [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para gerar as thumbnails, ela funciona tanto para arquivos locais quanto para arquivos online, este é um exemplo real do meu aplicativo que utiliza esta biblioteca:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GalleryHolder holder, int position) {

        GalleryItem item = mItems.get(position);

        holder.listener = mListener;

        if(!item.isFolder){

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            holder.ivThumb.getLayoutParams().height = dm.heightPixels / 5;

            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().override(holder.ivThumb.getWidth(), dm.heightPixels / 5).centerCrop();
            Glide.with(mActivity).load(item.getFile()).apply(options).into(holder.ivThumb);

        }

    }

    ...

    class GalleryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        GalleryListener listener;
        ImageView ivThumb;

        GalleryHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ivThumb = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_gallery_thumb);
            ivThumb.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), false);
        }
    }
```